# Number of onto functions

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

What are the number of onto functions from a set $\Bbb A $ containing `m` elements to a set $\Bbb B$ containing `n` elements.

I found that if $m = 4$ and $n = 2$ the number of onto functions is $14$.

But is there a way to generalise this using a formula? If yes, what is this formula and how is it derived?

**reference**

I referred to this question but my doubt was not cleared:
[How many one to one and onto functions are there between two finite sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333497/how-many-one-to-one-and-onto-function)

If not, Then what is the standard way of doing it?

If you explain this to me with an example please explain with the example of $m = 5$ and $n = 3$.

Comment: For readers in 2020: 1. you will have to understand exactly-none formula of Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, 2. Let $E_0$ means exactly $0$ of the elements in $\Bbb B$ that you sure it(they) won't be used as function value(s), then $E_0$ indeed counts the number of onto functions: $$\begin{align}\textrm{onto}(m,n)=E_0&=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j\binom{j}{0}S_j\\&=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j\color{blue}{\left[\binom{n}{j}(n-j)^m\right]},\end{align}$$ where the blue part $S_j$ is defined as: you're sure that $j$ of the values won't be the function values.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Obviously if $m<n$, there are no function from $\Bbb A$ onto $\Bbb B$, so assume that $m\ge n$. We’ll use an [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) argument. There are $n^m$ functions of all kinds from $\Bbb A$ to $\Bbb B$. If $b\in\Bbb B$, there are $(n-1)^m$ functions from $\Bbb A$ to $\Bbb B\setminus\{b\}$, i.e., functions whose ranges do not include $b$. We need to subtract these from the original $n^m$, and we need to do it for each of the $n$ members of $\Bbb B$, so a better approximation is $n^m-n(n-1)^m$.

Unfortunately, a function whose range misses **two** members of $\Bbb B$ gets subtracted twice in that computation, and it should be subtracted only once. Thus, we have to add back in the functions whose ranges miss at least two points of $\Bbb B$. If $b_0,b_1\in\Bbb B$, there are $(n-2)^m$ functions from $\Bbb A$ to $\Bbb B\setminus\{b_0,b_1\}$, and there are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of points of $\Bbb B$, so we have to add back in $\binom{n}2(n-2)^m$ to get

$$n^m-n(n-1)^m+\binom{n}2(n-2)^m\;,$$

which can be expressed more systematically as

$$\binom{n}0n^m-\binom{n}1(n-1)^m+\binom{n}2(n-2)^m\;.$$

Unfortunately, this over-corrects in the other direction, by adding back in too much. The final result, when the entire inclusion-exclusion computation is made, is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n-k)^m\;,$$

which can also be written $$n!{m\brace n}\;,$$ where ${m\brace n}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). The Stirling number gives the number of ways of dividing up $\Bbb A$ into $n$ non-empty pieces, and the $n!$ then gives the number of ways of assigning those pieces to the $n$ elements of $\Bbb B$.

Comment: its awesome comment! What is your reference? @BrianM.Scott I am looking for a book or article about it.

Comment: @user1062: Any decent book on combinatorics, and especially enumerative combinatorics, will have everything that I used. [This brief introductory text](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/cgt.pdf) [PDF] has everything that I used. Some of the other items in the list [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454339/undergrad-level-combinatorics-texts-easier-than-stanleys-enumerative-combinator) would also do; I like the two books by Miklós Bóna. All of these will also have far more than you need, however.

Comment: thank you very much:) @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @user1062: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is a little complicated. It is $n!S(m,n)$, where $S(m,n)$ is the appropriate [Stirling Number of the second kind.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind)

There are nice recursions for the $S(m,n)$, but no simple closed-form formula.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to think about this that more naturally shows how this problem maps to Stirling numbers of the second kind comes from Bogart in *Introductory Combinatorics*.  There is an exercise that asks us to come up with a recurrence relation for the number of functions from a set onto another set that has a similar form to the [recursive formula for binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Computing_the_value_of_binomial_coefficients).  To that end, we define a function $f(m,n)$ that is the number of functions from a set of size $m$ onto a set of size $n$.

Without loss of generality, we take set $\mathbb A$ to be integers $n \in \mathbb N, 1\leq n \leq m$, i.e., $\{1,...,m\}$.  Now we consider the number of elements in $\mathbb A $ that map to the same element of $\mathbb B$ as $m$ does.  The functions in which at least one other element of $\mathbb A $ maps to the same element as $m$ are counted by $n\times f(m-1,n)$ and the functions in which no other elements of $\mathbb A $ map to the same element as $m$ are counted by $n\times f(m-1,n-1)$, so we get

$f(m,n) = nf(m-1,n) + nf(m-1,n-1)$

Now, I'm no good at solving recurrence relations, but thanks to Brian we already have a potential formula for $f(m,n)$ so we can substitute it in and see if it checks out:

$f(m,n) = nn!{m-1\brace n} +n(n-1)!{m-1\brace n-1} = n!(n{m-1\brace n} +{m-1\brace n-1})=n!{m\brace n}$

Answer (score 2):

By the inclusion-exclusion principle, a Set $B$ containing $N$ distinct objects, with set of properties $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n$ (that the objects of the set $B$ may possess), and $N(B_i)$ being the number of objects having property $B_i$,the number of objects in $B$ having none of the properties $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n$ is given by

$N\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}\bar{B_i}\right)=N-N\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}B_i\right)$

$=N-\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} N(B_i)-\underset{1\leq i\neq j \leq n}{\sum\sum}N(B_i\cap B_j)+\underset{1\leq i\neq j \neq k \leq n}{\sum\sum\sum}N(B_i\cap B_j \cap B_k) - \ldots + (-1)^n N\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n B_i\right)\right)$

Now, for the mapping $f: A \to B$, with $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$, s.t., $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$, with $m\leq n$, let's define the property $B_i$ as $b_i \not \in B$, $\forall{i\in\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}}$, with $N=n^m$ being total number of possible mappings.

Then we have the number of onto functions

$=N\left(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}\bar{B_i}\right)$

$=n^m-\left(n(n-1)^m-{n \choose 2}(n-2)^m+\ldots+ (-1)^{n-1}{n \choose n-1}1^m\right)$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k{n \choose k}(n-k)^m$

(Notice the similarity of the above expression with that of  [The Matching Problem/Derangements - n letters to n people](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132855/the-matching-problem-derangements-n-letters-to-n-people))

Answer (score 1):

one can also get this by the following correspondence:No of onto functions is same as no of ways of distributing m distinct objects into n distinct containers(each container can receive any no. of objects)such that none of the container is left empty