# How to deduce the formula "distribution" in groups? What is the difference between "distribution" & "arrangement"?

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of ways in which $n$ different things can be **distributed** into $r$ different groups is $$r^n - \binom{r}{1} (r - 1)^n + \binom{r}{2} (r - 2)^n + \ldots + (- 1)^{r - 1} \binom{r}{r - 1}$$.

This is what my book wrote. Now, how to prove this? Also, as the title goes, what is the difference between **distribution** & **arrangement**?

Comment: Are you considering both the "things" and the "groups" to be distinguishable? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There is no $x$ in your formula

Comment: It is an InclusionExclusion argument. we are counting the functions from an $n$-element set **onto** an $r$-element set. Please see the Wikipedia article on Stirling numbers of the second kind. There have also been a number of relevant solutions on MSE.

Answer (score 1):

From the formula, it seems that by a distribution $d(n,r)$ it means partitioning an n-element set into r-sets such that none of the r-sets are empty.

Also, in that case $d(n,r)$ is the number of onto functions from a n-element set to a r-element set and you can find the derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334420/number-of-onto-functions).