# How many onto functions are there from a set with $5$ elements to a set with $3$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider functions from a set with $5$ elements to a set with $3$ elements.
(a) How many functions are there?
(b) How many are one-to-one?
(c) How many are onto?

a) Each element mapped to $3$ images.
   $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$

b) $0$

c) How do I do this?

Edit:
I tried doing this way.

EDIT:
There can be a set of cardinality {3,1,1} or {2,2,1}.

For {3,1,1}:
5C3 * 2C1 * 1C1 * 3!

For  {2,2,1}:
5C2 * 3C2 * 1C1 * 3!

And i realized my 3! is wrong. Should be * 3 only. Why is that so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of onto functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334420/number-of-onto-functions)

Comment: The number of partitions of the form $3, 1, 1$ is $\binom{5}{3}$ since a partition is completely determined by selecting which three of the five elements will be in the set of three elements.  Notice that $\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4\}, \{5\}$ is the same partition as $\{1, 2, 3\}, \{5\}, \{4\}$ since we do not care about the order of the sets, just what is in them.  The number of partitions of the form 2, 2, 1 is $\frac{1}{2} \binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$ since it does matter in which order we pick the two sets with two elements.  You can verify these calculations by listing the partitions.

Comment: As for the $3!$, it is correct.  Once, we have a particular partition, such as $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5\}$, we have three choices where to map the elements in $\{1, 2\}$, two remaining choices where to map the elements in $\{3, 4\}$, which leaves us with only one choice to which we can map $5$.

Comment: I dont understand why {1,2,3}, {4},{5} is the same as {1,2,3}, {5},{4}. Doesn't this mean they are 2 different onto functions? {123} mapped to 1st image. {4} mapped to second image. {5} mapped to third is different from {123} mapped to 1st image. {5} mapped to second image. {4} mapped to third

Comment: $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4\},\{5\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2,3\},\{5\},\{4\}\}$ are *distinct notations* for *the same set*, which is a partition of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. And $3!=6$ surjective functions $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ exist such that $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4\},\{5\}\}=\{\{1,2,3\},\{5\},\{4\}\}=\{f^{-1}(\left\{ 1\right\} ),f^{-1}(\left\{ 2\right\} ),f^{-1}(\left\{ 3\right\} )\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You correctly found that there are $3^5$ functions from a set with five elements to a set with three elements.  However, this counts functions with fewer than three elements in the range.  We must exclude those functions.  To do so, we can use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways of excluding one element in the codomain from the range and $2^5$ functions from a set with five elements to the remaining two elements in the codomain.

There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of excluding two elements in the codomain from the range and $1^5$ functions from a set with five elements to the remaining element in the codomain.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of surjective (onto) functions from a set with five elements to a set with three elements is

> $$3^5 - \binom{3}{1}2^5 + \binom{3}{2}1^5$$

Comment: +1 Equals $k!\times S(n,k)$ where $S(n,k)$ stand for [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Here $k=3$ and $n=5$.

Comment: Hi mind checking my edit?

Answer (score 3):

Hint on c)

The "onto"-function will induce a partition of its domain (as any function) and this partition (actually the fibres of the function) will - because it is onto - have exactly $3$ elements. So to be found is in the first place how many such partitions exist. A fixed partition gives room for $3\times2\times1=6$ functions.

So you end up with: $$6\times\text{number of partitions on }\{1,2,3,4,5\}\text{ that have exactly }3\text{ elements}$$

Also have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) (especially the counting of partitions).

---

A general formula for the number of onto-functions $\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,k\}$ is: $$k!S(n,k)$$where $S(n,k)$ stands for the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

Comment: I had not thought of doing the problem this way until I read your solution.  Once I got past the unfamiliar terminology (my knowledge is less sophisticated than yours) and counted the partitions, it made sense.  Thanks for providing it. (+1)