# How many onto functions can exist between two finite sets?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I approach this problem ? I tried to use combinations and permutations but I can't understand how to apply combinatorics .

I tried many things in vain . Please introduce new concepts to me if required .

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are two finite sets and if $|A|>|B|$, then there is no onto function from $B$ to $A$. You need to specify about cardinality of the sets.

Comment: See [Number of onto maps](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334420/number-of-onto-functions).

Comment: Thanks but in the other case ?

Comment: Did you mean "How many" rather than "How any" in the question title?

Comment: Let $A=\{1,2,...,k\}$ and $B=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and for simplicity write the mapping $f:A\to B$ as $f:[k]\to [n]$.

 - If $n>k$, there are no surjections.
 - If $n=k$, every surjection is a bijection and the number of maps is
   $n!$
 - If $n<k$, number of surjections is given by the [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://brilliant.org/wiki/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/): $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^k$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom In fact the formula $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^k$ is correct for all $k\gt0$ and even for $k=0$ if you rewrite it as $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^k.$

Comment: @David K    I meant  " How many " in the question title