# Let A and B be sets of 7 elements and 10 elements, respectively. (a) How many different functions possible from A to B? from B to A?

Tags: combinatorics

Let A and B be sets of 7 elements and 10 elements, respectively. (a) How many different
functions possible from A to B? from B to A? (b) How many different relations possible
from A to B? (c) How many of the functions from A to B are one-to-one? (d) How many of
the functions from B to A are onto?

(a) I am not sure how to approach this question. My guess is that since we could have a function per element and multiple elements and a function for all elements from A to B there could be 7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 28. From B to A there could be 10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1.

(b) I think there can be a max of 7 relations

(c) I would also think there are 7 but at this point and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a) for a function from A to B, how many choices of the image of the first element of A are there?  Each element of A has that many choices and the choices are independent, so you multiply.  for b) look up the definition of a relation.  It will give you a simple expression that is a large number.  For c) do like a), but each successive element has fewer choices because you can't reuse any elements in B.

Answer (score 0):

A) for $A\rightarrow B$, $10^7$ functions possible (for one element in $A$, there are $10$ possible images in $B$)
B) for $B\rightarrow A$ , $7^{10}$ functions are possible. (same logic)

C)Only $7!$ functions, one element=one image only

D)For this, [follow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334420/number-of-onto-functions)

Comment: Item B is answering the second half of A.  C is not correct.  The first element of A that you assign a value to has $10$ choices.